# Download speed limiter for Wifi interface on Android

Tags: java, android, apache-flex

How can I make download rate limitation (bandwidth) on Android phones.

I want to specify a specific Download rate(e.g. 100kbps) for the phone and prevent it from using all available bandwidth.

Comment: As a single limit imposed on all applications? As a limit that can be applied on selected applications? As a limit that applies to transfers that you are coding?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think, any of that cases will be very helpful to debug networking apps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this project has such capability.  [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy)  for Selenium type projects, assuming you are writing Android unit tests to test your app.